# Existing Heroku app and Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I have an existing Rails app at heroku.  I have a github account.

I'd like to use the Github Mac app to view/commit changes and push back up to Heroku.  Can this be done?  Or can the Github Mac client only push/sync with repos at Github?  Since the remote repo is already at Heroku, I'd just assume leave it there and not create a duplicate at Github too.

But, If this can't be done.  What would be the best way set this up so I can update my local repo, then push to Github, and push to Heroku?  All using the Github Mac app?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about github app, but I've been using SourceTree for this. Also, I wouldn't have heroku's repo as the main repo for the app. Create one on github, work with it and occasionally push to heroku's remote.

Comment: Also, I would advise to first familiarize yourself with git command line, and only then use GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the documentation, you [can use a non-GitHub remote](http://mac.github.com/help#faq-multiple-remotes) (like Heroku) also.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I just added my local repo - then changed "Primary remote repository" on the Settings page (per the link you mentioned) and it worked great.